# Can I use iconv to convert multi-byte smart quotes to extended ASCII smart quotes?

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv, extended-ascii

I have some UTF-8 content that includes multi-byte smart quote characters. I've found that this code will easily convert those characters to ASCII straight quotes (ASCII code 34):

```
$content = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $content);
```

OR

```
$content = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $content);
```

However, I'd rather convert these to extended ASCII smart quotes (ASCII codes 147 and 148 in Latin 1 encoding). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which contains "curly quotes" at 0x91-0x94 (145-148).

```
$content = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1252//TRANSLIT", $content);
```