# How do I prevent smart quotes symbols from being written to my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using this HTML to send user input to my database:

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="15"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
```

I parse it with `$description = $_POST['description'];` and insert it into my Mysql database with `INSERT INTO`

When I look at the record in my database description is this: `â€œThis is one of those books that you donâ€™t want to put down â€¦â€ Romantic Times`

It should be: `“This is one of those books that you don’t want to put down …” Romantic Times`

QUESTION: how can I save smart quotes and ellipses (...) to my database without them being converted to gibberish?

SOLVED: The solution I found that worked for me was to change my html page to UTF-8 everywhere, so the record would be displayed properly on the page. The record still contains the weird characters though. Here's the html code: meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 everywhere"

I also used `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');` in my PHP page, and now the database has proper text with now weird characters.

Comment: They are not gibberish, [they are in UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm). Just handle the character encoding properly (either use UTF-8 everywhere or convert your input text to the encoding you use).

Comment: There is no option for UTF-8 everywhere in Starfield Technologies Mysql...at least, not that I can see. Is there a way to set it to UTF-8 Everywhere, inside my php webpage? I'm using utf8_general_ci right now.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087309/can-i-use-iconv-to-convert-multi-byte-smart-quotes-to-extended-ascii-smart-quote, probably iconv()  function will rescue you.

Comment: You can try using `mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');` and/or `$con->set_charset("utf8");` before inserting into DB. My personal favorite is `$con->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. I set my webpage character set to UTF-8 everywhere:  meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 everywhere"

Comment: If you are successful at handle uft8 in mysql , pdf generation will be a headache for you with these characters in db,check the link I shared with you

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `CHARACTER SET = utf8` for everything:

- The MySQL database definition.

  ```
  CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATION utf8_general_ci;
  ```
- The MySQL table definition.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE mytable ( ... ) CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATION utf8_general_ci;
  ```
- The MySQL session.

  ```
  SET NAMES utf8;
  ```
- Apache virtual host setting.

  ```
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
  ```
- The HTML presentation.

  ```
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  ```

More Resources:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
by Joel Spolsky

[Character Sets Suck](http://www.slideshare.net/ligaya/character-sets) by Ligaya Turmelle