# str_replace for double quotes simply is not working

Tags: php, replace

I've used `str_replace` for many characters and it works perfectly. For the life of me it does not work with double quotes. It simply doesn't do anything:

```
$value = str_replace('"', '', $value);
```

This does not remove double quotes. Is there some Apache or PHP setting that stops this from working?

Edit: `trim($value, '"')` also does not work! I think i'm going mad.

Edit 2: AbraCadaver got it! Thanks it needed "

Comment: It works.  `$value` must not have quotes.  Maybe `&quot;`.

Comment: It works fine for me. http://codepad.viper-7.com/DO0ffV Make sure the double quotes are not the curly quotes.

Comment: maybe its *smart* quotes maybe its .. ?

Comment: Are you sure they normal double quotes not some other character.

Comment: My input is: "JAMES". When I echo value before and after the str_replace it is still "JAMES" and "JAMES"!

Comment: Wow! &quot; worked. $value = str_replace("&quot;", "", $value);

wtf that seems odd

Comment: @Vidarious: Where is your input coming from?

Comment: its not odd its just that your are replacing  `&quot;` and not `"`

Comment: @AngryGoomba look same in *browser*, unlikely to look same in *text editor*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$value = str_replace("&quot;", "", $value);
```

Thanks AbraCadaver

Answer (score 3):

Just reiniterating what someone else suggested, as it worked for both me and the original poster:

```
$value = str_replace("&quot;", "", $value);
```

Although, I was dealing with a single quote issue. What is odd is that the output from my php variable produced a `'` in the code, not a `&apos;`. If it were `&apos;` that output, it wouldn't break the html attribute I was loading it into. Example: `<element attr='&apos;'>`

Not sure myself how to explain. But, glad it got fixed. Hope the original question gets upvoted as it seems not trivial or without effort, but a confusing situation and understandably so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related gotchya. I was searching for `id="` based on what Chrome DevTools was showing, that being `id="identifier"`

After loads of time wasted, I did View Source. The generated code was surrounded by single quotes, not double, i.e. `id='identifier'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use that, but first convert the quotes you have which are non-ASCII "curly" quotes to ASCII quotes with this:

```
$content = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1252//TRANSLIT", $content);
```

See also: [Can I use iconv to convert multi-byte smart quotes to extended ASCII smart quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087309/can-i-use-iconv-to-convert-multi-byte-smart-quotes-to-extended-ascii-smart-quote)